# What is the best way to show loading in web socket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am building a chat app using Socket.IO and I am curious about how I should show loading indicator when subscribing messages as the message history will be received one by one.

Solutions i have so far:

- Emit loading messages and loaded messages event
- Using setTimeout to check next message received time, (ex: set 1s timeout to set loading to false, but if within 1s received message then set loading true and clear previous timeout) **(Not recommended btw)**

Any other better solution regarding this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what problem you're trying to solve.  Please describe in more detail what sequence of events happens and what you're trying to show the user.  Usually, you would make a request of the server, then show a "now loading" indicator and then when the response arrives, you clear the "now loading" indicator.

Comment: I am using websocket, so the data will be received when the event emitted on the server, and the chat histories will be received one by one

Comment: If the problem is that you don't know when you've received the last of series of chat history messages, then you probably should not be sending them all as individual messages (lots of individual messages are way more inefficient than a few larger messages).  You could also have the server send an initial message that tells the client how many messages are coming.  Of have the server send a message to the client that says all history messages have now been sent so it knows when they are done.  Three separate choices for you.